# How can I make an iframe taller when specifying a higher height doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, css, iframe

I have book cover images that are `318x424`, and what I am trying to do is specify an image, and below it a text link. The initial src is `about:blank` so that it won't be chewing up user bandwidth if the frame is not displayed by responsive design.

The HTML for the frame is:

```
<div style="width: 0; text-align: center;">
<iframe id="slideshow" border="0" frameborder="0" frameborder="no"
style="display: none;" width="318" height="725"
src="about:blank"></iframe>
</div>
```

The JavaScript is:

--EDIT: Code changed to take advantage of Ian's suggestion--

```
function size_book_cover()
    {
    if (jQuery(window).width() > 1200)
        {
        if (jQuery(window).width() > 1300)
            {
            var width = Math.min(jQuery(window).width() - 1100, 318);
            jQuery('#slideshow').attr('src', '/book_covers.cgi?width=' + width);
            jQuery('#slideshow').css('width',  width + 'px');
            jQuery('#slideshow').css('right', jQuery(window).width() / 8);
            jQuery('#slideshow').css('display', 'block');
            }
        }
    }
```

What happens instead in both Firefox and Chrome is that the iframe is given a slot the size of one of the pictures; the text link below can be scrolled down to, but is below the fold.

Any ideas why an iframe should fit the picture snugly when more height has been specified and the content is taller than the picture?

--ADDITIONAL EDIT--

One host page containing an iframe is at http://JonathansCorner.com/blacksmiths-forge/.

The guest iframe can be seen at http://JonathansCorner.com/book_covers.cgi?width=318.

Comment: Did you mean `document.getElementById('slideshow').style.width = width + 'px';` ? Notice the `.style` added in

Comment: Also, since you're using jQuery, be consistent and use it everywhere - for example, `document.getElementById('slideshow')` can be `jQuery("#slideshow")` and setting the `.src` can be `.attr("src", "/book_covers.cgi?width=" + width);`, and setting the width can be `.css("width", width);`

Comment: @Ian Thank you for helping improve my code. It's that bit cleaner, but it doesn't appear to address the image-snug iframe.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was addressed by adding the following line to size_book_cover():

```
            jQuery('#slideshow').css('height',  '575px');
```